# How can i re-run script in python language?

Tags: python, restart

Just one simple question... How to **re-run** script when it's over.

I'm sorry if question already answered. But I didn't find any useful answers...

Comment: Your question is not clear. IF you have the code in a file, you can always re-run it. Right?  You prob. will elaborate the way you run and re-run first. to make the question clear/specific.

Comment: Oh sry i mean when script is finished and closed to restart it. Like if im rerun it.

Comment: @KlemenHorvat-Novak You mean looping your program? if true, you just need to add ```while True``` in your code

Comment: Ye @FelixFilipi u're right

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to loop your code

```
while True:
  #Change this with your code
  print("hello world")
```